# Continuous image upload without relying on max_execution_time?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

We're developing a website where users may change their slider images. (fullscreen slider) Each image is around 2000px to 2000px and we allow users to upload as many images as they want in our HTML form (capped to 10).

Their upload speed will be pretty slow and I believe we'll easily pass the max_execution_time of PHP which is default to 30 seconds. We will also let users to upload some .rar/.zip files in the future capping at 100MB.

We had few ideas but I wanted to ask SO for a better solution/reviews.

1. We can change 30 seconds for alot higher value since we have access to PHP.ini and let users upload all images at once, but that may create performance related issues in long term. **(This is not an option!)**
2. We can make use of javascript in client size. Foreach image paths specified in HTML form, javascript may post it with XMLHttpRequest one by one and expect a response. If the response is true, javascript moves to the next images and attempts to upload it. (Profit: each image will start php itself and get their own 30 seconds lifetime.)
3. Javascript solution won't work in file uploads when the file is above 50MB. Customers are usually capping at 25kbps upload speed in target region so there is no way they can upload 50MB in 30 seconds. Similar to #2, we may use a script where uploaded file saves in bytes every 30 seconds and client continues to push remaining bytes, or anything alike.

Basically, how would you complete this task?
We don't want to rely on PHP.ini, so increasing max_execution_time shouldn't be an option.

Should we go with #2 for image uploads and what can you suggest for #3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into chunked uploads.

You'll need to use some sort of uploader script like [JUpload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupload/) or [plUpload](http://www.plupload.com/). You can specify how large the chunk of a file should be sent to the server. For example, if you have a 10MB file, you can chunk it to 1MB, so 10 1MB chunks would be uploaded to the server. In the case of a slow connection, just make the chunks smaller like 500KB.